# O que significa "sanitizar" dados?

Tags: php, segurança, terminologia

Estou fazendo um formulário, e estou realizando a parte de validação...

Vejo muito o termo `sanitize` ou `sanitizar`, o que isso significa?

Inclusive tenho visto algumas funções no `php` que levam esse termo em seus parâmetros.

Comment: Já ouvi o termo "higienização" também.

Comment: O correto seria "sanear" ou "higienizar". Usar "sanitizar" não é nem um anglicismo, é erro de ortografia mesmo.

Comment: Possui alguma referência para sua afirmação ou é apenas uma opinião? @epx

Comment: Já ouvi falar o termo santificar

Comment: Tem uns dados que parecem "satanizados" .... desculpem a piada ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Eliminar trechos de texto em uma entrada de dados que tenham características de metadados, e que por isso podem causar algum problema de segurança.

Por exemplo: em HTML os caracteres < > & fazem parte do *markup*, se uma string de dados contiver esses caracteres, causará problemas porque o browser interpretará como HTML. Na hora de enviar ao browser, tais caracteres devem ser reescritos como &lt; &gt; &amp; respectivamente. (Aliás, eu tive de fazer isso aqui enquanto escrevia minha resposta, do contrário os símbolos substitutos não apareceriam corretamente!)

É muito comum ter que tirar certos códigos HTML e principalmente JavaScript do que poderá ser publicado em alguma página do sistema, e esse *script* comprometer a experiência do usuário, modificar informações ou até criar facilidades para infectá-lo.

Ou pode limpar dados que servirão como nome de um diretório ou arquivo para não acessar o que não deve.

Outra limpeza que pode ser útil é eliminar trechos de SQL que podem ser injetados na consulta e fazer estrago. Em SQL as aspas simples e duplas delimitam strings, portanto dados com esses caracteres sem saneamento podem desarranjar os comandos SQL. Em geral há técnica melhor para evitar que isso aconteça.

É possível fazer alguns saneamentos específicos, só permitindo que determinado dado bem formado seja aceito, um e-mail por exemplo, ou só número, etc. Tem uma [página com alguns desses filtros possíveis no PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php). E a [página com informações sobre o assunto](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

De [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_filter.asp):

Sanear dados = Remover qualquer caracteres ilegais do dado.

Auto-explicativo, serve para normalizar dados para que você possa trabalhar com eles posteriormente.

Answer (score -2):

Sanitizar tem o mesmo fim, eliminar ou resumir informações e imagens que dão informações excessivas ou muito complexas. No meio militar, um arquivo sanitizado, geralmente, é um arquivo que tem a grifagem de textos, corte de imagens, branqueio de texto e de equações, estes, que, caso não fossem eliminados, dariam informações sensíveis, que afetaria a segurança da pessoa, organização e/ou nação.
É bastante comum a sanitização ocorrer em arquivos que saíram de secreto, super-secreto, confidencial e classificado, e entraram para "desclassificado", mas sem acesso ilimitado ao público, muitas vezes, um arquivo desclassificado é disponível, somente, para organizações governamentais e empresas contratadas.

O termo civil é mais no meio da área que afeta o sigílo empresarial, pessoal e organizacional, mas sem relação com orgãos militares/governamentais.

Comment: Aqui falamos estritamente em TI. Outros contextos vão além de nosso escopo.