# O que são metadados?

Tags: terminologia

Estava pesquisando sobre "sanitizar" dados e encontrei **[esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186360/8063)** do @maniero, que cita:

> *"Eliminar trechos de texto em uma entrada de dados que tenham*
>   *características de **metadados**, e que por isso podem causar algum*
>   *problema de segurança."*

Gostaria de entender o seriam *metadados* e qual a aplicação/utilidade deles, se é que possuem?

Comment: Eita, por que os downvotes? D:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Meta, do grego (μετά), significa "atrás" ou "além". Metadados são informações sobre um dado.

Pense em uma foto tirada de uma câmera fotográfica:

[image]

O dado em si é a imagem. É o que você vê acima. Os metadados poderiam ser:

- Que câmera tirou essa foto?
- Em que papel foi revelada?
- Onde essa foto foi tirada?
- Quem tirou essa foto?

São informações sobre o dado. É o meta, o atrás e o além da imagem em si.

Fica claro que esse não é um termo da área de tecnologia, e sim aplicável a qualquer tipo de dado, objeto, fotografia, software ou coisa que você pode imaginar. Esse é um termo que [está em ascensão](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=metadata&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmetadata%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmetadata%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMetadata%3B%2Cc0) desde os anos 90, com a popularização dos computadores e da internet.

### Contextualizando

#### Arquivos em disco

Para contextualizar em tecnologia da informação, vejamos os metadados de um arquivo:

- Tamanho do arquivo
- Extensão do arquivo
- Nome do arquivo
- Tamanho ocupado em disco

Todo arquivo no sistema operacional tem metadados. Isso é guardado em disco e ocupa espaço. Portanto, um arquivo de 1 kb tem na verdade 1 kb + tamanho dos seus metadados.

#### JSON APIs

Uma das especificações para se construir Web APIs é a [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org). Seguindo essa especificação, suponha que você tenha uma API de listagem de produtos paginada:

```json
GET /api/produtos

{
  "produtos": [ ... ],
  "meta": {
    "paginaAtual": 1,
    "proximaPagina": "api/produtos?pagina=2",
    "paginaAnterior": null
  }
}
```

Veja que existe um nodo `meta` que não tem nenhuma ligação com um produto, que é o que esse *endpoint* fornece. Ele é sobre a paginação. É a informação além do dado e sobre ele.

#### HTML

Nas páginas da internet o esquema não é diferente. Uma página como seu perfil do Facebook deveria conter sua timeline, seu nome, sua foto e afins. Além de todos esses dados, existe uns a mais, dedicado aos metadados.

É para isso que serve a tag [`meta`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) do HTML. Ela foi feita para ser lida por máquinas e não por um usuário final. São informações sobre a página.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
  <meta name="author" content="John Doe">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Aqui, nesse exemplo do W3C, os metadados da página seriam uma descrição, as palavras-chave, o autor da página e etc.

#### Bancos de dados

Os DBMS de bancos relacionais também tem metadados. Uma tabela de pessoas pode conter entidades com nome, data de nascimento e CPF. O conteúdo são as entidades. Mas se eu faço a pergunta: "quais são as colunas da tabela de pessoas?", esta é um questionamento sobre os metadados dessa tabela.

Alguns exemplos de metadados de uma tabela de banco de dados:

- O nome da tabela
- O tamanho da tabela
- O número de linhas da tabela
- As colunas da tabela e sua tipagem

Esses dados, de fato, estão armazenados em algum lugar. No SQL Server pode visualizá-los na tabela `sys.columns`. Um exemplo:

```
SELECT name, column_id
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Pessoa.Cpf');
```

Se quer ler mais sobre, veja [Querying the SQL Server Catalog](http://Querying%20the%20SQL%20Server%20System%20Catalog).

#### Linguagens de programação

A metaprogramação trata dessa parte nas linguagens. O Maniero respondeu uma [pergunta minha sobre a diferença entre metaprogramação e reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276112/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-metaprograma%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-reflex%C3%A3o), que vale a pena a leitura. Lá ele definiu a metaprogramação de forma breve:

> um paradigma que permite a manipulação do código de
>   forma mais geral, você programa como o código deve ser programado.

Um exemplo de um código lendo a si mesmo em Ruby:

```
class Developer 
  def self.backend
    "I am backend developer"
  end

  def frontend
    "I am frontend developer"
  end
end

p Developer.class   => Class
p Class.superclass  => Module
p Module.superclass => Object
p Object.superclass => BasicObject
```

#### Formato de imagem BMP

Um exemplo interessante é o formato `.bmp` (bitmap image file) de imagens. Se você observa o conteúdo desse arquivo de forma crua, verá que ele segue o seguinte padrão:

> [image]

Pode ver que muito dessa informação não é a matriz da imagem em si, mas sim, metadados dessa imagem. Como você mencionou não há problema em sanitizar parte dessa informação em muitos casos.

Comment: Mt boa explicação. Eu já sabia o que era em outras coisas, mas no âmbito da programação eu estava em dúvida.

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado!

Comment: Entendi. São coisas "além" do que os olhos podem ver. Informações que não estão explicitadas mas existem.

Comment: Gosto de definir como informação sobre o dado.

Comment: Metadados são metainformações sobre um dado. Mas aí eu teria que fazer outra pergunta "Oq são metainformações?" rss

Comment: Sobre metadados, se quiser aprofundar (se tiver preguiça posso abrir uma resposta com outros exemplos complementando, mas não vejo necessidade): um banco de dados saber a nível de consulta quais são as tabelas, quais as colunas dentro dessas tabelas, qual o tipo dentro de cada coluna, a quais colunas uma chave estrangeira se refere da classe primária e como mapeia na classe que aponta para a primária; se você tiver esse acesso durante a consulta, você está pegando dados sobre os dados do banco. Web semântica também tentou usar muitos metadados para fazer descobrimentos de serviços, SOAP também

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso!! Vou complementar sim. Obrigado